# Opencascade GetLogbook() c++ invalid initialization error

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, opencascade

I got the following code from [Example 1: iteration and execution of functions](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_user_guides__ocaf.html) from manual that explains how to use the Open CASCADE Application Framework (OCAF).

```
// The scope of functions is defined.
Handle(TFunction_Scope) aScope = TFunction_Scope::Set (anyLabel);

// The information on modifications in the model is received.
TFunction_Logbook& aLog = aScope->GetLogbook();
```

I get error in the second line, compiler mingw64:

> No viable conversion from 'opencascade::handle<TFunction_Logbook>' to
> 'TFuntion_Logbook'
>
> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
> 'TFunction_Logbook&' from an rvalue of type
> 'opencascade::handle<TFunction_Logbook>'

Comment: What about the error message is unclear? It seems to pretty accurately tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I thought that placing const was enough, but no, same error.
I am migrating a code from a linux platform to windows. In linux not error compiling this.